# Create a Custom Distribution of Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, backup, custom-distributions, livedvd, remastersys

I want to make a custom distribution of my Ubuntu 15.04 i recently upgraded from 14.04 installed and configured lots of software i need and i want to make an install-able iso with all the apps i installed . Is there a way ? since remastersys don't work after Ubuntu 12.XX .it will be very helpful thanks for reading.

Comment: no brother i want to make an ISO from my existing system like aconis true image in windows. the link you have shown is similar to kickstart in rhel i don't want that

Comment: yes but in that case i have to create scripts and do that all over again just like kickstart server in rhel .I want to use the packages i have along with my existing ubuntu system to make an live iso that i can install and all the softwares i installed changes i made are already in it.It used to be so simple with remastersys-gui but they stopped the project.so im asking is there any alternatives to remastersys ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UCK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/157562#157562), which is installable from the Ubuntu Software.

A good guide to using it can be found in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/157562#157562) answer.